# htaccess with regex not working properly!

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I can't seem to get the regex in my htaccess redirect working:

`RewriteRule [\./:_a-zA-Z0-9]*\/(web-browse(r|rs)-benchmarks)[a-zA-Z0-9-/\.:?=]*(|html) /web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/ [R=301,L]`

Even `.+(web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome).+` won't work

I'm getting this error in chrome:

> The www.domain.org page isn’t working
>
> www.domain.org redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 5):

What seems to be happening, is your rule is being matched and then  apache is sending a 301 redirect response telling the browser to generate a new request for

```
/web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/
```

Chrome is generating this request - as instructed, but when your webserver see's this new request - *your rule is matching that request too* - **again** telling chrome to generate another request for `/web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/` resulting in an infinite loop.
You can check with:

```
$ curl -I www.domain.org/web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/
```

You will probably see something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 
Server: apache
Location:  www.domain.org/web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is telling chrome/curl/etc to re-request the page it just requested
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2016 08:56:02 GMT
[...]
```

You can try break the loop by with a conditional check - so assuming that

```
www.domain.org/web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/
```

is the actual URL you want to serve, and your current rule uses `[R=301,L]`  so Im assuming a 301 external redirect is what you want.

```
# this RewriteCond tells apache if this URL is requested, thats the URL we want
# so serve it instead of rewriting it.
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" !^/web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/
RewriteRule [\./:_a-zA-Z0-9]*\/(web-browse(r|rs)-benchmarks)[a-zA-Z0-9-/\.:?=]*(|html) /web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Really well detailed answer here, looks like you even ran the checks too - nice one.

Comment: Can I have more than 1 condition? Like if /web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/ or /web-browsers-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/ or /web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/index.html or 0/10/205/web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/ etc. is requestend THEN redirect any of these to to /web-browser-benchmarks-firefox-chrome/

Comment: Currently my htaccess has got like 160+ lines of redirects. That's a mite much in my opinion.